# How to install OCLint in mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, static-analysis

I'm trying to install OCLint in my mac with MAC OS X mavericks 
Its documentation [here](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/intro/installation.html) says that

*Following code snippet is an example for the .bashrc or .bash_profile file that is sourced when terminal launches.*

```
OCLINT_HOME=/path/to/oclint-release
export PATH=$OCLINT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

How can I accomplish this? whether I need to create .bashrc or .bash_profile file, or add to existing file. Where can I locate .bashrc or .bash_profile file

Comment: "OCLint is a standalone tool that runs on Linux and Mac OS X platforms."  =>  What makes it a programming question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `.bashrc` in your home directory (i.e. `/Users/yourname/.bashrc`) already then just append these lines, otherwise create a new `.bashrc` containing these two lines. Then do this:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 11):

Install Oclint with Homebrew is quickly and helpful solution.
Open terminal and install homebrew first:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install Oclint 0.11.1 with this command

```
brew install https://gist.github.com/TonyAnhTran/e1522b93853c5a456b74/raw/2f440240fe99634771a3f2353c0c53a43c2d0fb2/oclint.rb
```

To create .bash_profile in terminal:

```
Type "cd ~/" to go to your home folder
Type "touch .bash_profile" to create your new file.
Edit .bash_profile with your favorite editor (or you can just type "open -e .bash_profile" to open it in TextEdit.
Type ". .bash_profile" to reload .bash_profile and update any functions you add.
```

Update on 31-Jul-2017:

before_install:

- brew cask uninstall oclint
- brew tap oclint/formulae
- brew install oclint

Answer (score 9):

```
brew tap oclint/formulae
brew install oclint
```

More details are here: https://github.com/oclint/homebrew-formulae

Answer (score 2):

Those files should be in your home directory, but they will be hidden by default due to the leading dot. You can [enable the "Show all files" feature](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/11/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-107-lion-and.html) to see them in Finder. Or, if you're comfortable using the Terminal app, edit the files from the terminal and append the lines for OCLint.